# ASP.NET opening email attachements

Tags: asp.net, email

I have an ASP.NET web forms application that pulls email from an IMAP account.  I am using an IMAP control from nsoftware IP*Works to pull the emails.  In order to download and save the attachments one does this...

```
for (int part = 0; part < imaps1.MessageParts.Count; part++)
{
    if (imaps1.MessageParts[part].FileName.Length > 0)
    {
        imaps1.LocalFile = "C:\\Users\\someguy\\Documents\\" + imaps1.MessageParts[part].FileName;
        imaps1.FetchMessagePart(imaps1.MessageParts[part].Id);
    }
}
```

But I don't want it downloaded; I want the attachment to open.

How would I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the attachment contents to `Response.OutputStream` rather than a file on disk.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot open an attachment directly on a mailserver. If you want to open it you always have to download it first (at least to a temporary directory).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any source code off-hand, but what you'll need to do is construct an HTTP response with the appropriate headers for content type and content disposition, and then send the file stream with the response.